# Кто-нибудь может пояснить как запускаются программы NetCoreApp?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Кто-нибудь может пояснить как запускаются программы NetCoreApp?

Здесь есть только dll. Как её запускать? Только через консоль `dotnet dll`? Можно создать для запуска exe? (Windows 10)

```
\StartApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\StartApp.dll
\StartApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\StartApp.deps.json
\StartApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\StartApp.runtimeconfig.json
\StartApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\StartApp.runtimeconfig.dev.json
\StartApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\StartApp.pdb
```

Comment: А как это вы получили dll? какой у вас тип проекта? Должен быть exe, по идее.

Comment: @VladD а оно не через dotnet запускается?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 по умолчанию так делает для Консольное приложение (Net Core). Тип выходных данных - консольное приложение

Comment: Возможно это поможет [.NET Core – How to publish a self-contained application (.exe)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/): `dotnet publish -c release`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Процесс достаточно подробно расписан в [.NET Core 1.1 – How to publish a self-contained application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2017/03/19/net-core-1-1-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application/)

Минимальный набор изменений:

1. Добавить в csproj нужный RuntimeIdentifier:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
     <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. Восстановить зависимости:

   ```
   dotnet restore
   ```
3. Опубликовать с указанием рантайма:

   ```
   dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64
   ```

Бинарники будут собраны в папку `bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64`.

Аналогично для других рантаймов - достаточно вписать несколько RuntimeIdentifiers, и при сборке указать нужный:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

---

```
dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.16.10-x64
dotnet publish -c release -r osx.10.11-x64
```

Способ работает и для других типов приложений, например, для ASP.NET Core.